# Cannot connect to socket in same domain

Tags: apache-flex, flash, security, sockets, cross-domain

I have a Flex web app (compiled to regular SWF) that tries to connect to a (binary, not XML) socket on its own server. So if the swf is at `example.com/app.swf`, the socket is `example.com:12869`

This should be possible, AFAIK, but when I try to connect I get a security error saying that `example.com/app.swf` cannot access `example.com:12869`.

Even though it shouldn't be needed, I also have a `crossdomain.xml` file containing

```
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

but it doesn't help.

What can I do?

You can see the app [here](http://axa3.axastudios.nl/game/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that by default Flash will request the policy from the socket, meaning it sends `<policy-file-request/>` to the Socket - if you have the possibility to add it to your server implementation, you can have a look at how [that guy](http://coderslike.us/2009/01/23/flash-socket-code-and-crossdomain-policy-serving/) fixed the same sort of problem.

You can also use `Security.loadPolicyFile("http://axa3.axastudios.nl/crossdomain.xml")` before initiating the socket connection to force it to load your policy first. I'm not 100% sure if this works for Socket connections though, the [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/00000349.html#wp140657) (search for "Socket policy files") are slightly confusing.

Comment: I will try, of course, but why is that even necessary when the domains are the same?

Comment: The port is not the same, and that means you're in a different context from a security sandbox point of view.

Comment: Well, i've followed the docs, but it doesn't work quite yet. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570663/flash-doesnt-connect-to-socket-even-though-policy-allows-it

Comment: Did you try the other way I mentionned? I mean just loading the xml file through your http server with Security.loadPolicyFile(). It seems to me like this could work.

Comment: If that doesn't cut it, I guess the only way is to have your server running on port 12869 respond to the `<policy-file-request/>` with a policy, and then proceed to normal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [my Apache 2 module](http://code.google.com/p/mod-socket-policy/source/browse/trunk/) - it listens at the port 843 and answers socket policy requests